# Input autofill font-size in newest chromium version (above 95)

Tags: css, input, font-size, autofill

I'm interested in possibility for changing font-family and font-size for input autofill.

There was some methods in oldest chrome version, but unfortunately this possibility was removed since 95 version of chromium.

```css
    &:-webkit-autofill,
    &:-webkit-autofill:hover,
    &:-webkit-autofill:focus,
    &:-webkit-autofill:active {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px transparent inset;
        transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;

        /* this line can change text color for new chrome version */ 
        -webkit-text-fill-color: ${primary};
    }

    /* old way for changing font properties in autofill */ 
    &:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: pink;
    }
```

So do you know any method for doing such a thing in latest chromium version(101) ?